# How to declare a default boolean parameter to be used by all plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to be able to control if my matplotlib plots use the option `rasterized=True` or not in a flexible way without changing it in all my plot calls.

Is there a way to control it via rcParams? I looked up all the keys of that dictionary but could not find anything that seemed related.

This almost makes me believe that I have to write a decorator to change the plot call or is there an easier way?

Comment: what's the problem with switching it on/off on individual axes basis?

Comment: as I wrote, I have existing code with many plot calls that would be hard to refactor. Guess some sed magic could do it, but I thought there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about set the `get_rasterized()` in `Artist` class:

```
import pylab as pl

pl.Artist.get_rasterized = lambda self:True

fig, ax = pl.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3,2])
fig.savefig("test.pdf")
```

Comment: I don't understand how I can verify with the pdf if the plot was rasterized before? How would I know? Because, interestingly, in a QT backend, the rasterized plot is still zoomable without any obvious quality loss.

Comment: Just open the pdf and zoom in.

Comment: Plots are rasterized when saving them, not when visualising

Comment: well, at least in the IPython notebook there is a substantial easing on the rendering engine when I plot several 28000 item plots using the option rasterized=True. When I don't use it, after several plots of that size, in-line editing becomes unbearable slow, so at least your statement is imprecise. Maybe it's because the IPython notebook does some kind of prelim/tmp saving to display it?